# Get "class" attr from <body> of $.get() object

Tags: jquery

I need to get the class attribute from the body element of a page object retrieved with $.get(). In my example below, fullContent is set to the object but I can't select the body element... I'd rather not resort to text manipulation to get this

```
$.get(url, refreshFullContent);

var refreshFullContent = function(response, status, xhr)
{
    fullContent = response;   
    var bodyclass = $(fullContent).find("body").attr("class");
    $("body").attr("class", bodyclass);
}
```

Is there a way to get this with selectors on the object (like I'm trying to do in this example)? If not, what is the best way to get this from the text? xhr.responseText contains the string of the entire response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting a full HTML document response, you won't get consistent behavior between browsers.

Some browsers will strip away the `head` and `body` elements.

You could try this, but no guarantees:

```
var fullContent = '<div>' + response + '</div>';
var bodyclass = $(fullContent).find("body").attr("class");
$("body").attr("class", bodyclass);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this didn't work. I'm going to try using the $.ajax method instead of $.get

Comment: @andrhamm: Unfortunately, using `$.ajax` won't give any different result. `$.get` is just a convenience wrapper for an `$.ajax` GET request. Have you verified that `response` actually contains the content you expect?

Comment: Yeah it contains the entire HTML document I'm requesting. The odd thing is, I can grab any other element from the response. I'm pulling a specific element into the page (but the styling for that element is influenced by the body classes). My workaround was to print (server side) the same classes from the body tag into a data attribute in the element that I can select. From there I can just do this: `var bodyclass = $(".content.lower").attr("data-bodyclass");` then `$("body").removeClass().addClass(bodyclass);`

Comment: @andrhamm: That's probably a better workaround. The way you had it,  you could likely use `.filter()` in some browsers, but it would still break in others that destroy the `head` and `body` elements. Your solution of switching the class to an attribute on a nested element is probably the best.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to get the body class from `$.get`.

```
$.get(url, refreshFullContent);
var refreshFullContent = function(response, status, xhr)
{
    $("body").attr("class", /body([^>]*)class=(["']+)([^"']*)(["']+)/gi.exec(response.substring(response.indexOf("<body"), response.indexOf("</body>") + 7))[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i tried the solution of user113716, but unfortunatly, body class was always undefined. but this solution works for me:

```
$("body").attr("class", data.match(/body class=\"(.*?)\"/)[1]);
```

while data is my ajax response and body has to look like this:

```
<body class="classname...">
```

means right after the body element comes the class attribute (or you have to rewrite the regex).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get(this.pathname, function(response) {
        var $dom = $(document.createElement("html"));
        $dom[0].innerHTML = response; // Here's where the "magic" happens

        var $body = $(dom).find("body");
        // Now you can access $body as jquery-object
        // $body.attr("class");

    });
});
```