# Body class from AJAX html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX function

```
        type: "GET",
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){

            },
            error: function(){ },
            complete: function(){ }
        });
```

ofcourse that "data" represent entire document with `<html>` but I only want to get class of body element from this data variable.

Does anyone know how to do that? To get class of body element from retrieved data?

Thank you very much for every advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097723/get-class-attr-from-body-of-get-object

It's works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in plain JavaScript:

```
success: function(data){
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
    // Your class(es)
    var docClass = doc.body.getAttribute('class');
    // Garbage collection, you don't need this anymore.
    parser = doc = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly :) Do you think that this task is too much complicate for loading each page via ajax on wordpress webpage?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are doing, if you are just getting the class name then yes, but if you are actually parsing the content and loading it, then it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = $('body', data).attr('class');
```

Comment: Sorry but this just throw "Undefined"

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using jQuery.load

```
$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );
```

The above code fetches the target Id from article.html

Answer (score 0):

If the `data` is string, you can parse it to HTML and take whatever you want. Example:

```
var data = "<div class='test' id='divID'> Hello </div>";

var parsedDiv = $.parseHTML(data);

$(parsedDiv).attr('class'); // returns 'test'
$(parsedDiv).attr('id'); // returns 'divID'
```

**edit** I missed the part that `entire data is html`. You can skip the parsing step. Use it directly jquery object. like:

`$('body', data).attr('class');`